# How to print text vertically using geraldo?

Tags: reportlab, geraldo

I'm trying to format a report generated in PySped with Geraldo. And I couldn't find any way to print the text vertically (by rotating it by 90 degrees).

I see properties like top, left, right, bottom but I couldn't find any property that permits me to rotate the text or manipulate it using any sort of angular transformation.

Is that possible? And if so, how?